# Datatype Map: Navigate to parent element name, from current element

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

For all period elements I need to use a generic url, which is stored in parallel level in same JSON data / XML map. I am therefor trying to navigate to the element "url", using current node as startpoint. I can do that using the index number but not the key name.

I activate test-3 but commented-out the other tests, since test-3 gives wanted result.

**Question:** Is it possible to query using key name instead of index number, towards a XML map?

If its not possible to use relative navigation in map, then I am fine with other ways of querying the element "url".

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{

"url": "http:www.example-10.com",

"period": {
      "0": {"startDate": "2016-01-01","endDate": "2016-12-31"},
      "1": {"startDate": "2015-01-01","endDate": "2015-12-31"}
    },

"balance": {
      "0": {"instant": "2016-01-01"},
      "1": {"instant": "2015-01-01"}
    }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:periods="http://www.example.com/2"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <root:report>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
        </root:report>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process "period" -->

    <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'period']">

      <xsl:for-each select="./*">

            <periods:startDate>

              <xsl:attribute name="url">

                <!-- Test [1] get's all values from current node -->
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="."/> -->

                <!-- Test [2] get's first value from current node  -->
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="./*[1]"/> -->

                <!-- Test [3] Attempt to find parent element "url" with index  -->
                <xsl:value-of select="../../*[1]"/>

                <!-- Test [4] Attempt to find parent element "url" with name  -->
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="../../url"/> -->

              </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:value-of select="./*[1]"/>


        </periods:startDate>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Wanted result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root:report xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
             xmlns:periods="http://www.example.com/2"
             xmlns:root="http://www.example.com/1">
   <periods:startDate url="http:www.example-10.com">2016-01-01</periods:startDate>
   <periods:startDate url="http:www.example-10.com">2015-01-01</periods:startDate>
</root:report>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/*:map/*:string[@key = 'url']` or declare the `fn` namespace (with e.g. `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`) and use it instead of the wildcard with e.g. `/fn:map/fn:string[@key = 'url']`.

Or upwards with e.g. `../../fn:string[@key = 'url']`.